# isinstance of double

Tags: python, floating-point, isinstance

This might be a silly question but I read somewhere that floats in Python are equal to doubles in C++. So if I want to check whether a variable is a double or not, should I use the following:

```
isinstance(v, float)
```

or this one:

```
isinstance(v, double)
```

Comment: Python doesn't have a double type. All floating point numbers are floats. But type-checking is normally discouraged in python.
Why do you need to do this? There might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 8):

You can't check for a C/C++ type in Python. If you want to know if a value is a floating-point number, then `isinstance(v, float)` does it for you. If that returns true, you've got a floating-point value that corresponds to a C `double` (in CPython), which on typical platforms means a 64-bit IEEE float. Details of the FP format are available as [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info).

If you want smaller floats for some reason, then install [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and use its `np.float32` or `np.float16` types.

Answer (score 2):

sorry, there is no `Double` in python, python only have `floats` and `int`.

In python 2.x we've `long int` too, but not in 3.x.(don't confuse long int with C's long)

Comment: And Long integers. Don't forget those. (But still != a C `long`)

Comment: @FelixBonkoski Python 3.x removed `long int`.

Comment: You're right.  I just live in this imaginary world where nearly everyone still uses Python 2.X :P